# how to lower a power bank USB 5.1v /2.1amps output to 4.5v to power a 150 lumens LED flashlight

Tags: led, resistors, usb, diodes

I would like to use a power bank to power a 150 lumens flashlight 3 AAA batteries operated ( https://www.harborfreight.com/ultra-bright-led-portable-worklightflashlight-64005.html ).

I already connected a USB cable to the + and - terminals in the batteries' compartment.  The probkem is that the power bank is too much for the flashlight and it got burned when I power it with the 2.1amps output of the powerbank.

My power bank has two different outputs: a 5.0V/1A and a 5V/2.1A.  The 1amp output is not able to light the flashlight completely; it runs well for about 2 seconds and then it starts to flash intermittently.   The second 2.1amps output is able to supply the current to keep the light on, however, after maybe 20 seconds it burns partially the LED and 4 of the 10 LEDs in the strips do not light up and the rest light emission is very low.  So, I think the voltage supplied by the power bank is too strong for the electronic board/LED strip!?

The real reading in output of the USB port is 5.12v.

What I need/wanted, is to be able to reduce the voltage by adding a resistor to the battery terminal (usb cable connection) to 4.5V which is the right voltage required by the flashlight.

I have another two flashlights (same model) and I will try to replace the little board inside that send the power to the LED strip to see exactly if the board was damaged or if the strips was the burned one.

I would really appreciate your help with this.

**added: I forgot to mention that the flashlight has a 10 Ohms 5% resistor at the + terminal where the USB cable is soldered (to connect to the power bank).**

Comment: Are you sure the flashlight does not have a control circuit? Most of them do

Comment: Your question itself is based in some substantial misunderstanding.  This is not a very realistic project to attempt without an understanding of the flashlight's internal implementation.  Your best bet would be to source a flashlight that comes with a suitable rechargeable battery.  Some are available which are both flashlights, and also function as powerbanks for other sources.  Or get a little desk/work/reading light designed to plug into a USB port.

Comment: Henry did you understand my answer is within the tolerance of the battery.

Comment: "What I need/wanted, is to be able to reduce the voltage by adding a resistor to the battery terminal (usb cable connection) to 4.5V which is the right voltage required by the flashlight." - okay then, do that. You'll need to calculate the resistor value and power rating.

Comment: Adding a resistor to your battery terminal is not what you need or want. Try it if you want, you will need a 2 Ohm 10 Watt resistor to get 2.1A at 4.5V. (That resistor is going to be bigger than your flash flight by the way)

Comment: What you actually need, is to know what the internal board does. Battery operated LEDs often cheat on their circuits because they can rely on properties of the battery to provide limits.

Comment: This looks like it's a really cheap flashlight that has no internal means of regulation, and relies on the internal resistance of the AAA pack to allow the voltage across the LEDs to drop to the 3 - 3.5V they typically operate at. Forcing them to run at  5V  will increase the current draw dramatically, and they won't last long. Since you have a voltmeter, measure the voltage across the terminals when running on the AAAs, and the current if you can. Then you'll have an idea what you need for a regulator. Maybe a resistor is all that's needed, but it needs choosing to get the right current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJWmwb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should operate about 
350 mA for a 1W LED  (initially) and then decay towards 10% of this after 24 hrs.

However AAA Alkaline batteries are expected to decay in < 2hrs at this rate and the product page indicates 24 hrs of service ( including dim service)

LED's of this type are rated up to 150 Lumens per Watt and 0.35A*3.2V=1W  THe AAA batteries often have an average ESR of 1 Ohm or less and thus also limit the current to the LED.

[image]

You  can expect the Rs for those diodes to make a subtle difference initial brightness and shorter battery life with the 3A diode. Self heating for the 1N400x should be ~ 1/4 W initially. You may compare  the curves of Forward Voltage drop to see the difference,  The 3.5A diode has a lower bulk Rs and thus will make the LED slightly brighter intiially ( maybe not noticable) and slightly shorter operating time.

My formula for silicon diodes is \$V_f= 0.6V_{(V_{th})}+\dfrac{I_f}{I_{rated}}*0.4V\$ for 1V at max current with 25% tolerance.  For white LEDs the threshold is ~ 2.85V and Rs depends on the Mfg tolerances for rise above this and 1/Pmax.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Looks like the diode is the easier, safer way to make it work.  WhaT do you think about changing the 1N400x for a 1N540x?    1A vs 3A in the 1N540x series, but I am not sure if the voltage drop will be the same...

Comment: 3A diode will increase LED brightness initially and reduce operating time. It's a tradeoff. Both will work.  Do you want to compare (typ) Vf vs If with my formula? and Table spec tolerances and guess on LED tolerances to make a guestimate or choose brighter or longer use.  Your choice.  3A diode is a good choice too.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Lame disgruntled users who show themselves disrespect and shall go nameless

Comment: If you  verify my diode approximation formula, remember it.

Comment: Thanks again!  Very well explained!  appreciate it!